# Cheking if an entry exists in another table using cursor

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

My task is to insert entries from one table to another by using parametrized cursor. Here's what I have tried

```
DECLARE 
    oldroll NUMBER;
    newroll NUMBER;
    oldname VARCHAR2(25);
    newname VARCHAR2(25);
    CURSOR c_orollcall (roll_no NUMBER,name VARCHAR2) IS SELECT * FROM o_rollcall;
    PROCEDURE procedure_2;
    
PROCEDURE procedure_2 AS
    BEGIN
        OPEN c_orollcall;
        LOOP
            FETCH c_orollcall INTO oldroll ,oldname;
            SET @count = 0;
            SELECT roll_no INTO @count FROM n_rollcall WHERE EXISTS (oldroll);
            IF @count>0  THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ENTRY ALREADY EXISTS');
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO n_rollcall VALUES (oldroll,oldname);
            END IF;
            EXIT WHEN c_orollcall%NOTFOUND;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c_orollcall;
    END;
/
BEGIN
    procedure_2;
END
/
```

I am getting a bunch of errors and dont' understand how to proceed further.I previously posted a question about this too but it generated more errors .
here's the problem statement:

Write a PL/SQL block of code using parameterized Cursor that will merge the data available in
the newly created table N_RollCall with the data available in the table O_RollCall. If the data in
the first table already exist in the second table then that data should be skipped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use parametrized cursor to only export distinct entries to a new table with no entries to begin with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73677098/how-to-use-parametrized-cursor-to-only-export-distinct-entries-to-a-new-table-wi)

Comment: You should start with reading the manual. [Declaring variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-568AC23F-1BC3-444E-855E-BF2EC4EEB14B) [References to Identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-397990B7-9C45-4D37-A8A4-478FC116E898) [Assigning Values to Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-356CB656-68ED-4869-8C67-FE93A78AEC9A)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use an extra variable to store the result and check it in `IF` codition

```
 SET count = 0;
 SELECT COUNT(roll_no) INTO count FROM n_rollcall WHERE EXISTS (oldroll);
```

Updated code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_2 AS
   DECLARE count INT default 0;
    BEGIN
        OPEN c_orollcall;
        LOOP
            FETCH c_orollcall INTO oldroll ,oldname;
            SET count = 0;
            SELECT roll_no INTO count FROM n_rollcall WHERE EXISTS (oldroll);
            IF count>0  THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ENTRY ALREADY EXISTS');
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO n_rollcall VALUES (oldroll,oldname);
            END IF;
            EXIT WHEN c_orollcall%NOTFOUND;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c_orollcall;
    END;
/
```

Comment: Line/Col: 6/14 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 6/18 PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
Line/Col: 7/14 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 7/41 PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
Line/Col: 8/16 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: @AryanSharma you need to declare it at the begining of your procedure,see my updated answer

Comment: I am still getting errors

Comment: @AryanSharma [as documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-B91BEA99-974B-4CE7-8B28-A5B78A6918F7) SET isn't used to assign values to variables.